# 'stationary' almost disjoint families

Tags: set-theory, large-cardinals

Consider almost disjoint families on regular $\kappa > \omega$ consisting only of stationary sets.

My question: Is there **consistently** an upper bound $<2^\kappa$ on the size of such a 'stationary' almost disjoint family (under suitable large cardinal assumptions)?

E.g. a Woodin cardinal implies the consistency of '$\text{NS}_{\aleph_1}$ is $\aleph_2$-saturated', which implies that any s.a.d. family has size $\leq \aleph_1$. However, as $X_i \cap X_j$ is not only non-stationary but bounded in $\kappa$, maybe weaker assumptions also imply the consistency of 'Every s.a.d. family on $\aleph_1$ has size $\leq \aleph_1$' ? **(solved)**

EDIT: The following cases for $\kappa$ remain open:

Always require $2^\kappa > \kappa^+$:

- $\kappa=\kappa^{<\kappa}$ and $\text{sad}< 2^\kappa$ ?
- $\text{sad} < \text{sat}(\text{NS}_\kappa)$ ?
- and, of course, $\text{sad} < \text{min} \{\text{sat}(\text{NS}_\kappa), \text{mad}\}$ ?

Comment: At least in the case for s.a.d. family of size $\aleph_2$, I think that you can argue that the non-saturation of $NS_{\aleph_1}$ implies that there is also a s.a.d. family of size $\aleph_2$ (for every $S_\alpha, S_\beta$ in the antichain take $D_{\alpha,\beta}$ club disjoint from $S_\alpha \cap S_\beta$. Now, take $E_\beta$ to be the diagonal intersection of $D_{\alpha,\beta}$ for $\alpha < \beta$, using some enumeration of $\beta$ of order type $\leq \omega_1$. The collection $S_\alpha \cap E_\alpha$ with be s.a.d.). This doesn't answer your question in the non-GCH case.

Comment: Now I don’t understand the point of the question, after the edit.  There is consistently (without large cardinals) an upper bound $<2^{\omega_1}$ on the size of an almost-dijsoint family of subsets of $\omega_1$.  So in this model, such a cardinal also bounds the size of stationary almost-disjoint families.

Comment: I think that 'SAD family' would intuitively be a family of sets such that the symmetric difference of any two is non-stationary. An almost disjoint family of stationary sets would be just that.

Comment: @AsafKaragila symmetric difference being nonstationary means that they’re all in the same equivalence class mod NS, and in particular have stationary intersection.

Comment: @Monroe: Err, yes, of course. I meant the intersection of any two is non-stationary.

Comment: My impression is that Johannes asks whether it is consistently possible to arrange that the bound on the size of the length of the sad's is strictly less than the saturation of NS.

Comment: @Monroe: I didn't know that the size of a.d. families can consistently be bounded. Furthermore, I found your answer and your comment really helpful; no need to delete them.

Comment: @Stefan You are pretty much right.

Comment: And I would also be interested if the bound of the sad's can be strictly below the bound of the ad families, e.g if $\kappa=\kappa^{<\kappa}$ so there exists an ad familiy of size $2^\kappa$

Answer (score 4):

First let us show that consistently there is no such bound, along with $2^\kappa$ larger than any prescribed cardinal. Assume $\diamondsuit_\kappa$.  This is consistent with any large cardinal assumption and any value of $2^\kappa$, by forcing with $Add(\kappa,\theta)$.  This principle states:

> There is a sequence $\langle a_\alpha : \alpha < \kappa \rangle$ such that for every $X \subseteq \kappa$, $\{ \alpha : X \cap \alpha = a_\alpha \}$ is stationary.

It is easy to see that if $X \not= Y$, then the set points where the diamond sequence guesses $X$ is almost-disjoint from the set where it guesses $Y$.
Thus under $\diamondsuit_\kappa$, there is an almost-disjoint family of stationary subsets of $\kappa$ of maximal size.

Second, let us show that consistently there is such a bound.  This is inspired by exercise 23.11 in Jech.  Suppose GCH holds in $V$.  Force with $Add(\omega,\omega_3)$.  In the extension, $2^{\omega_1} = \omega_3$.  We will show that there is no almost-disjoint family of subsets of $\omega_1$ of size $\omega_3$.  Suppose otherwise and let $\langle \dot A_\alpha : \alpha < \omega_3 \rangle$ be a name for a counterexample.  For each pair $\alpha<\beta$, it is forced that $A_\alpha \cap A_\beta$ has size $<\omega_1$, and by the ccc, there is some ordinal $\delta_{\alpha,\beta}$ such that $1 \Vdash \dot A_\alpha \cap \dot A_\beta \subseteq \check \delta_{\alpha,\beta}$.  By the Erdos-Rado theorem (and GCH), there is some $X \subseteq \omega_3$ of size $\omega_2$ and a $\delta <\omega_1$ such that $\delta_{\alpha,\beta} = \delta$ for all $\alpha,\beta \in X$.  Thus it is forced that $\{ A_\alpha \setminus \delta : \alpha \in X \}$ is pairwise disjoint.  This is impossible.

Comment: I wonder if the existence of a bound is consistent with continuum $=\omega_2$.